# Javascript or Jquery to get div by key of div and change value of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of tables.

```
var tables = "";
for (var i = 0; i <= data.length - 1; i++) {
    if (data[i].current_order == null) {
        tables += '<button class="table_btn" value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].table_number + '</div>';
    } else {
        tables += '<button class="table_selected" key="' + data[i].current_order + '"value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].table_number + '</div>';
    }
```

And tables have two color, when it is busy or not busy. If there is `current_order` in table, it shows busy. What I want to do is that when a user clicks empty table, it gets `table_id`, changes class from `table_btn` to `table_selected` and add `key`of div, which is `current_order`.

I use `phoenix-framework` for my backend, so when a  user clicks an empty table, it creates order and passes value of clicked `table_id` and created `order_id`. But I am not sure that how can I get a table by `value` of table div and put `key` into div...

Can anyone give me advice for this??

Comment: this is easy stuff but we need to  see some of the html produced, busy and unbusy to get a better answer

Comment: In the code above, `table_btn` is unbusy table and `table_selected` is busy table. So I want to make it like when a user clicks button, changes class and inputs key..

Answer (score 0):

So as you tagged Jquery, i'm gonna post this. Change key for ID and you can do the following. I would then wrap the add table and remove table in functions where u pass in the `data[i].current_order` into and use that.

**Edited based on user feeback, not tested**

```
/*If you are not comfortable using the variable 'This',
  you can just pass in the id of target table and 
  change the syntax to $("#"+targetTable)*/

var tables = "";
for (var i = 0; i <= data.length - 1; i++) {
    if (data[i].current_order == null) {
        tables += '<button class="table_btn" value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].table_number + '</div>';
    } else {
        tables += '<button class="table_selected" id="' + data[i].current_order + '"value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].table_number + '</div>';
    }

// On Click set table to busy
$(".table_btn").click(function(){
   addTable($(this).val(), $(this));
});

// Add table function
function addTable(tableId, targetTable){
  $.ajax({
  url: "YourBackEndHere",
  data: tableID
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
        $(targetTable).removeClass("table_btn");
        $(targetTable).addClass("table_selected");
        $(targetTable).attr("id", data[i].current_order);
  }
 });
}

// On click set table to empty
$(".table_selected").click(function(){
  removeTable($(this).val(), $(this));
});

// Remove table function
function removeTable(tableId, targetTable){
  $.ajax({
  data: tableId
  url: "YourBackEndHere",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
        $(targetTable).removeClass("table_selected");
        $(targetTable).addClass("table_btn");
        $(targetTable).attr("id", "");
    });
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, btw, i have many buttons of `table_btn`, I am afraid that with your answer, it will affect all `table_btn` to change to `table_selected`.. How can I use `value` to choose specific button that I want to change it to `table_selected`?

Comment: the variable $(this) will only change the clicked table and nothing else

Comment: Since I have to click for sending data to server, and get data (`current_order`) from server, I can't use this approach... Do you know how can I get specific value(`table_id`) of `table_btn`?

Comment: I mean that I can't get `current_order` by just clicking... now when a user clicks an empty table, it sends request to server to create order, and server sends `table_id` and created `order_id`. So I think that I need to get table by `table_id` from server, change class and input value of `current_order`

Comment: Yes, i also added that part in the description before the code. Will write a simple ajax example and edit the question for you now..